# Node.js: Controllable concurrent while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I have a mongodb collection of 1.7 million records. Each record is an ID number. I need to read off each ID number, do some requests to another service, transform the data, write it to a different collection, and remove the original ID record if all was successful.

I want a script that does those things indefinitely until the collection is empty, with specifiable concurrency (i.e. max 3 requests at any time).

Normally I would use Bluebird's `map`, which can specify number of concurrent promises, but there is no input array (unless I were to read off all the input records into memory, which I am not going to do).

What I want is essentially a concurrent while loop, i.e.: (pseudo-javascript)

```
promiseWhile(queueNotEmpty, 3){
  readFromQueue
    .then(doc => {
      return process(doc);
    })
    .then(result => {
      if(result == "empty") // (or whatever)
        queueNotEmpty = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: You should be able to go through all the records using `var stream = collection.find().batchSize(3).stream()` function. Then you can read the batch of 3 records in data event `stream.on('data'. fun....)` You can pause the stream and resume. This might help you http://www.davecooper.org/working-with-large-mongo-databases

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb's cursor to asynchronously iterate over all records. For having three workers working on it, wrap the task into an async function and call that multiple times:

```
 const cursor = db.collection("records").find({});

 async function process() {
   while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
     const record = await cursor.next();
     //...
   }
 }

 await Promise.all([ process(), process(), process() ]);
```

*(I'm not sure wether the mongodb driver supports concurrent calls to `.next()` though, you should test that)*

---

Otherwise this Semaphore implementation might help:

```
 function Semaphore(count = 1) {
  const resolvers = [];
  let startCount = count;

   return {
     aquire() {
       return new Promise(resolve => {
         if(startCount) { resolve(); startCount -= 1; }
         else resolvers.push(resolve);
       });
     },
     free() { 
       if(resolvers.length) resolvers.pop()(); 
       else startCount += 1;
     },
     async use(cb) { 
       await this.aquire(); 
       await cb(); 
       this.free() 
     },
     async done() {
       await Promise.all(Array.from({ length: count }, () => this.aquire()));
       startCount = count;
     },
   };
 }
```

[Running Demo](https://jsbin.com/konelopita/edit?console) 
In your case it is usable as:

```
 const connectionSemaphore = Semaphore(3);

 (async fuction() {
    while(await cursor.hasNext()) {
      const record = await cursor.next();
      /*await*/ connectionSemaphore.use(async () => {
        // Do connection stuff concurrently
      });
    }

    await connectionSemaphore.done();
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something like this twice recently.  My problem didn't involve that many records, and I needed to combine the results into a single data structure, but I think this could be a start toward what you're looking for.

Generalizing those solutions gives me something like this:

```js
// processQueue :: ((Number -> Promise [a]), Number, (a -> b), (c, [b]) -> c), c) -> Promise c 
const processQueue = (queue, count, process, combine, init) =>
  queue (count)
    .then ( items => items .map (process) )
    .then ( promises => Promise .all (promises) )
    .then ( curr => curr .length
      ? processQueue ( queue, count, process, combine, combine(init, curr) )
      : combine (init, curr)
    )
```

This takes five parameters:

- `queue` is a function that takes a number and returns a promise for a list of values
- `count` is a number
- `process` is a function that converts one of those values into another type
- `combine` is a function that combines a target type and a list of that second type into the target type
- `init` is the starting value for the reducer

It returns a promise for a value of that target type.

I can't really demonstrate with your infrastructure, but it's not too hard to build up a simple example.  First, we can write a dummy `queue` function that returns promises for groups of up to `n` items until there are no more, and then a promise for an empty list.  Here's a silly version:

```js
const queue = ((v) => (count) => Promise .resolve (
  Array .from ( {length: Math .min (count, 10 - v + 1) }, () => ( { id: v++ } ))
)) (1)
 
queue (3) .then (console.log) //~> [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
queue (3) .then (console.log) //~> [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}]
queue (3) .then (console.log) //~> [{id: 7}, {id: 8}, {id: 9}]
queue (3) .then (console.log) //~> [{id: 10}]
queue (3) .then (console.log) //~> [] // (and will forevermore return the empty list)
```

Then we can combine it with a function that processes one item, a reducer that simply concatenates arrays, and an empty array to start with, to get something like this:

```js
const processQueue = (queue, count, process, combine, init) =>
  queue (count)
    .then ( items => items .map (process) )
    .then ( promises => Promise .all (promises) )
    .then ( curr => curr .length
      ? processQueue ( queue, count, process, combine, combine(init, curr) )
      : combine (init, curr)
    )

const queue = ((v) => (count) => Promise.resolve (
  Array .from ( {length: Math .min (count, 10 - v + 1) }, () => ( { id: v++ } ))
)) (1)


processQueue(
  queue, 
  3, 
  ( {id} ) => ( {square: id * id} ),
  (a, b) => a .concat (b),
  []
) .then (console.log)
//~> [{square: 1}, {square: 4}, {square: 9}, ..., {square: 100}]
```

Although this looks at first like it might have problems with recursion depth, we're leaving our current stack frames in each `.then(...)`.  You can see that this still works if you replace `10` in `queue` with `100000`.  (I didn't have the patience for a million!)

In your case, if you don't need to return anything from your processing function, and therefore don't need to do any combining in a reducer function, this could clearly be simplified a bit.  But if you need to do anything there, even just reporting counts of successful transformations versus errors, then this full version might be appropriate.

---

Now I'm off to fix my recent code to use this abstraction...